# Shading an area bounded by curved paths between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am drawing a graph of sorts in `TikZ`, and I have several connected nodes in a cycle, and I would like to shade the area bounded by paths between those nodes. My problem is that the shading is not consistent with the arcs between the nodes (I have drawn the arcs between the nodes separately). My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\draw (a) to [bend right=30] (b);
\draw (a) to [bend left=30] (d);
\draw (b) to [bend right=30] (c);
\draw (c) to [bend right=30] (d);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (a) to [bend right=30] (b) to [bend right=30] (c) to [bend right=30] (d) to [bend right=30] (a);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\draw (a) to [bend right=30] (b);
\draw (a) to [bend left=30] (d);
\draw (b) to [bend right=30] (c);
\draw (c) to [bend right=30] (d);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (0,0) to [bend right=30] (2,0) to [bend right=30] (2,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,-1.4) to [bend right=30] (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried two approaches. The first, I used node names as anchors for the shading, but this does not cover all the area bounded by my curves. It seems that the shading is using the outer edge of the nodes as anchors than the center. The second, I used the coordinates of the nodes as anchors, but this covers too much. As far as I can tell, this is caused by (a) the drawn arcs between the nodes having a shorter distance to bend the same amount, and (b) the radii of the nodes not being all equal, due to the varying size of the characters. The result is this:

[image]

I would like to keep the drawn arcs between nodes as they are (even though they are not symmetric across the central axes), and would like to shade the area bounded by those paths and the outer boundaries of my nodes, in effect this:

[image]

Any tips in this regard are appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should try to draw arcs and lines from the center of the nodes. This can be done with the help of `positioning` library of tikz.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt,fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\draw (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center);
\draw (a.center) to [bend left=30] (d.center);
\draw (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center);
\draw (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center) to [bend right=30] (a.center);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\draw (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center);
\draw (a.center) to [bend left=30] (d.center);
\draw (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center);
\draw (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (0,0) to [bend right=30] (2,0) to [bend right=30] (2,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

The problem here is the curves appear over the nodes. This is due to the sequence of their drawing. This indicates that you should draw the nodes later. But if we do so, tikz won't know the points `(a.center)` etc and hence an error is thrown out. The remedy will be to draw the nodes twice (before and after drawing the curves and fill the nodes with `white` color) like the below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt,fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\draw (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center);
\draw (a.center) to [bend left=30] (d.center);
\draw (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center);
\draw (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (0,0) to [bend right=30] (2,0) to [bend right=30] (2,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,0);
\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which looks **inappropriate**!

As suggested by **Claudio Fiandrino** the `backgrounds` library can be used to push some objects to the background.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt,fill=white,minimum size=4ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center);
\draw (a.center) to [bend left=30] (d.center);
\draw (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center);
\draw (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center) to [bend right=30] (a.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[state] (b) at (2,0) {$b$};
\node[state] (c) at (2,-1.5) {$c$};
\node[state] (d) at (0,-1.5) {$d$};
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw (a.center) to [bend right=30] (b.center);
\draw (a.center) to [bend left=30] (d.center);
\draw (b.center) to [bend right=30] (c.center);
\draw (c.center) to [bend right=30] (d.center);
\path[fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (0,0) to [bend right=30] (2,0) to [bend right=30] (2,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,-1.5) to [bend right=30] (0,0);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

From this, we get

[image]

Another approach I suggest you is to use `coordinates` and draw everything using them in the proper sequence in which the objects are to be overlay-ed. Further, the size of letters `a` and `b` are not same. Hence your circles will have varying radius. This can be fixed by either adding `phantom` space or defining the  `minimum size` for the node.  The code will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black,fill=white, very thick,inner sep=3pt,minimum size=4ex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (2,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (d) at (0,-1.5);
\draw (a) to [bend right=30] (b);
\draw (a) to [bend left=30] (d);
\draw (b) to [bend right=30] (c);
\draw (c) to [bend right=30] (d);
\path[draw,fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (a) to [bend right=30] (b) to [bend right=30] (c) to [bend right=30] (d) to [bend right=30] (0,0);
\draw (a) to (b);
\draw (a) to (d);
\draw (b) to (c);
\draw (c) to (d);
\node[state] at (a)  {$a$};
\node[state] at (b)  {$b$};
\node[state] at (c)  {$c$};
\node[state] at (d)  {$d$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Danke schon! New command `\coordinate` learned.

Comment: Nice, +1. But you can also add a different approach: the `backgrounds` library. In your first code, by simply enclosing inside `\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}...\end{pgfonlayer}` the commands drawing the gray shape you'll get the same final result.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Nice suggestion. Added to the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

Somewhat more compact.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{state/.append style={circle,draw=black,fill=white,
                              minimum size=4ex,very thick,inner sep=3pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (2,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (d) at (0,-1.5);
\draw (a) rectangle (c);
\draw[bend right=30,fill=gray!50,opacity=.5] (a) to  (b) to (c) to (d) to (a);
\foreach \x in {a,...,d}{\node[state] at (\x)  {$\x$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I remember correctly you are better off with avoiding the overwrite (well actually use another name) of the `state` style which is used also in `automata` library or at least append your style.

Answer (score 9):

1. Declare coordinates.
2. Draw the shaded area with the help of these coordinates.

   - The bended lines are drawn in the same path as the shading
   - `fill opacity` makes sure that the lines aren't shaded as well.
3. Draw nodes.

   - `fill=white` is used to hide the part of the shaded area.
   - `\mathmakebox[\widthof{d}][c]{\vphantom{d}\c}` is used to get the same size for all nodes (and needs the `mathtools` package).
     You also could use a combination of `minimum size` and `inner sep`, but you don't necessarily get the real minimum size. If you specify a `minimum size` that is smaller than the size of the biggest node, you still get differently sized nodes. If you set it to a size greater than the biggest node, you don't get the tightest possible size (which doesn't hurt necessarily).
     Additionally, node tests from nodes that are on the same vertical position use the same base line which I find more pleasing than the `.center`ing. (One could combine the `.center` solution with this, of course, see below. That solution also uses `\strut` instead of `\vphantom`.)
4. Connect nodes

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (2,0);
\coordinate (c) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (d) at (0,-1.5);

\path[draw,fill=gray!50,fill opacity=.5,bend right=30] (a) to (b)
                                                           to (c)
                                                           to (d)
                                                           to (a);

\foreach \c in {a,b,c,d} {
    \node [state,fill=white] at (\c) (n\c) {$\mathmakebox[\widthof{b}][c]{\vphantom{d}\c}$};
}
\draw (na) edge (nb) 
      (na) edge (nd)
      (nb) edge (nc)
      (nc) edge (nd);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Outputs

[image: Output]

### Code with `.center` and `\strut`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,inner sep=3pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \c/\cx/\cy in {a/0/0,
                        b/2/0,
                        c/2/-1.5,
                        d/0/-1.5
} {
    \node [state,fill=white] at (\cx,\cy) (\c) {$\mathmakebox[\widthof{d}][c]{\strut \c}$};
}
\draw (a) edge (b) 
      (a) edge (d)
      (b) edge (c)
      (c) edge (d);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=.5,bend right=30] (a.center) to (b.center)
                                                             to (c.center)
                                                             to (d.center)
                                                             to (a.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output with `.center` and `\strut`

[image: Output with .center and \strut]

Comment: NICE I also like `\vphantom` - I was trying to use `\phantom` to get the node sizes equal, but it was giving me whitespace as well. Props for that.

Comment: Nice ? no ! the correct options is `minimum size` with `inner sep` here.

Comment: @AlainMatthes It's true, it's not nice. But `minimum size` has its disadvantages.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Indeed, `minimum size` does actually make it look nicer. I'm just excited about `\vphantom` solving other unrelated positioning problems.