# Why does PGF not draw the lines all the way for named nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Minumum Working Example

```tex
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path   (0, 0)  node (a) {}
        (1, .2) node (b) {}
        (1, 1)  node (c) {}
        (.2, 1) node (d) {}
;

\draw [red]
        (a) [fill] circle (.03)
        (b) [fill] circle (.03)
        (c) [fill] circle (.03)
        (d) [fill] circle (.03)
;
\draw [red]
        (a)  -- (b)  -- (c)  -- (d)  -- cycle
;
\draw [blue, shift={(2, 0)}]
        (0, 0)  [fill] circle(.03)  --
        (1, .2) [fill] circle(.03)  --
        (1, 1)  [fill] circle(.03)  --
        (.2, 1) [fill] circle(.03)  --
        (0, 0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As above, when specifying the nodes by their co-ordinates (blue) the lines reach the place but for the named nodes (in red) they do. Also, `--cycle` doesn't work with named nodes.

I suspect that it has something to do with node having a border or something. Anybody knows the exact reason for this behavior?

Comment: Check the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 17.11 "Connecting Nodes: Using Nodes as Coordinates". You might need path operation `(0,0) coordinate` or `(0,0) node[coordinate] {}`.

Comment: More info: the size of `(0,0) node (a) {}` is controlled by the default setting `shape=rectangle, inner sep=.3333em`.

Comment: You might find this helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81848/86 (and there are other useful quedtions linked to that one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. `nodes` has a minimum size, that you can see if you `draw` them. And lines between nodes stop at their borders being or not they drawn.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path   (0, 0)  node[draw] (a) {}
        (1, .2) node[draw] (b) {}
        (1, 1)  node[draw] (c) {}
        (.2, 1) node[draw] (d) {}
;

\draw [red]
        (a) [fill] circle (.03)
        (b) [fill] circle (.03)
        (c) [fill] circle (.03)
        (d) [fill] circle (.03)
;
\draw [red]
        (a)  -- (b)  -- (c)  -- (d)  -- cycle
;
\draw [blue, shift={(2, 0)}]
        (0, 0) node[circle, draw, fill, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0pt] {} --
        (1, .2) node[circle, draw, fill, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0pt] {}  --
        (1, 1) node[circle, draw, fill, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0pt] {}  --
        (.2, 1) node[circle, draw, fill, minimum size=1mm, inner sep=0pt] {}  --
        (0, 0)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]